# How to get major, minor, etc. version number of a program in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

A program returns a version string of this regex type `[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}` on the command line. Therefore the output looks like this:

```
C:\users\user\desktop>a.exe --version
Version: 1.22.53.4134
```

I save the output to a variable `Version` by this **get-version-info.bat**

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims=: " %%i in (`a.exe --version`) do (
    if /i "%%i"=="Version" set "Version=%%j"
)
```

To solve my exact problem I only need the **major** and **minor** release number(s), but a general, adaptable solution would be also good of course.

How to get major and minor version number of the program in batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this single command line in your batch file:

```
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:. " %%I in ('a.exe --version') do if /I "%%I" == "Version" set "Version=%%J.%%K"
```

The delimiters for splitting up the line output by `a.exe` are colon `:`, point `.` and space   as specified with `delims=:.` .

Of interest are only the first 3 substrings (tokens) as specified with `tokens=1-3`. The first substring being `Version` is assigned to specified loop variable `I`. The second substring being `1` is assigned to next loop variable according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) which is `J`. and the third substring being `22` is assigned to loop variable `K`.

Comment: Works nice, but I need to add a line: `set "Version=%Version:.=,%"` to get  back the version number with dots.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. On my test with processing the line `Version: 1.22.53.4134` from a text file by __FOR__ instead of output of an application `a.exe` which I don't have, the environment variable `Version` had the value `1.22` after batch file execution. The dot is a fixed character in `set "Version=%%J.%%K"`. So either your question does not contain real data or you have made something wrong if you need an additional line. Also your command line replaces all dots by commas in version string. You can use `%%J,%%K` instead of `%%J.%%K` if you want a comma between.

Answer (score 1):

Add the dot to the delims, extend the tokens and compound your Ver with the wanted elements:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4* delims=:. " %%i in (`a.exe --version`) do (
  if /i "%%i"=="Version" set "VerMAjorMinor=%%j.%%k"
)
```